# conversion from '::size_t' to 'int' requires a narrowing conversion

Tags: c++

I'm trying to implement a container class using the code given in the Chapter 18 of 'Programming Principles and Practices using C++'. And when I write the code for the initialization using initializer_list I get this error: 'conversion from '::size_t' to 'int' requires a narrowing conversion'.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<string>
#include<algorithm>


class vector
{
public:
    vector(int s) 
        :sz{ s },
        elem{ new double[sz] }
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < sz; i++)
            elem[i] = 0.0;
    }

    vector(std::initializer_list<double>lst)
        :sz{ lst.size() }, elem{ new double[sz] }
    {                                  //compiler points to here for the error
        std::copy(lst.begin(), lst.end(), elem);
    }

    ~vector() { delete[] elem; }

    int size() const { return sz; }

    double get(int n) const { return elem[n]; }
    void set(int n, double d) { elem[n] = d; }
private:
    int sz;
    double* elem;
};
```

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: `lst.size()` is a size_t, which is unsigned. Since unsigned types can contain larger values than the equivalent signed type you have a narrowing conversion. It's unclear what you're asking though. You can cast it if you like, or use () instead of (), but the best thing to do is to use size_t instead of int unless you expect your container to have a negative size.

Comment: @RetiredNinja It's also possible for `int` to be 32 bits and `size_t` to be 64 bits, which is narrowing regardless of signedness.

Comment: @melpomene That's true, but in the end the same problem and I didn't want to make it too complicated. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're trying to convert a `size_t` into an `int`. Assuming 32-bits, `size_t` can hold up to 2^32 because it's unsigned, whereas `int` can only hold 2^31 (because it can have negative values also).

When you do this:

```
vector(std::initializer_list<double>lst)
    :sz{ lst.size() }
```

If `lst.size()` is greater than the value stored by an `int`, then the value can't properly be stored. The solution would be to just use `std::vector` internally, and get rid of the `sz` member, but seeing as though it looks as if you're trying to make your own `vector` class, you should just make `sz` a `size_t`, since it better represents what you're trying to do. After all, it's not as if your `vector` can have `< 0` elements in it.

Comment: Another good way of saying "make your types makes sense" `:)`